What is the meaning of the 'ride out the clock'?
What is the meaning of the 'ride out the clock'?

Sol: Some things there’s no good way to do.  How do I tell the woman I’ve loved for forty years that I can’t be with her if I want to be happy?
FRANKIE: You don’t!  Ride out the clock!  Stay miserable.  I’ve got news for you: the next chapter ain’t that long. (then, realizing) Wait.  Is this why you got the Cialis??

I could not find it in any dictionary, but one of the sites says
"ride out the clock means to wait until there is no time left".
How does it come to have that meaning?  Is that an idiom?
It is in the drama Grace and Frankie,  https://tvwriting.co.uk/tv_scripts/Collections/Comedy/Grace_and_Frankie/Grace_and_Frankie_1x01_-_The_End.pdf
Thank you very much.

It's sorta like Just serve your time and don't do anything hasty. In contexts where unless you actively change the situation or take risks, the end result will be in your favour by default.

@Lambie: Duh. By pointing out that there's a far more common usage in British English that's been around for centuries, whereas run out the clock is a relatively recent idiom that won't mean much at all to the average Brit. How exactly does your comment advance the discussion?

@Lambie: Don't be daft! My linked chart clearly shows that run out the clock edged out serve your time in BrE two just decades ago (when the Internet made it much easier for AmE usages to cross the pond). Probably many of the BrE matches are misclassifications anyway. And even in AmE it only gained ascendancy in the 60s. Please stop telling me what I should do. Do I do that to you?

You really are being embarrassingly nit-picky. My first comment was true, and I'm only fishing out support for it because you're trying to make an issue of it. Pointlessly.

Serve your time means or is like run out the clock? That's misleading because in serve your time you are being punished and means: this bad time will finish and better times will come, and in running out the clock, you are already winning...The two are completely different.

"Serve your time" sounds like doing time in prison! :D

I am the OP.  I thank Mari-Lou A very much for editing by adding the context.  I thought the question would be obvious without the context. And I thank everybody else a lot for posting comments.

It was borrowed from sports but it is also a mixed metaphor:
to run out the clock
So, you're winning but probably won't make any more goals, so you just keep playing without being offensive in your moves to keep the ball away from the other team so it doesn't score.
run out the clock
So, here, it just means keep going in the relationship for as long as it lasts. The guy also then says: there's not that much time to go.
It's sort of a mixed metaphor: to ride out a storm and he put it with clock.

+1 for mixed metaphor, which is a generous way of putting it.

I don't really see it as a mixed metaphor. One can ride out many things - a storm, a recession, a boss' bad mood, or simply a period of time. Here "clock" is used as metonymy for a duration of time which one is riding out. It's not a mixed metaphor to "ride out the week", and not much more mixed to "ride out the clock". "Clock" isn't a metaphor here, it's a metonymy.

I'd make a distinction between "to ride out the clock" and "to run out the clock".  The latter means to act in a manner that consumes as much time as possible, without necessarily being productive, so as to preserve the current status. That's more or less what you said.  But the former is more passive.  It does not imply actively working to consume time, but only continuing -- perhaps enduring or holding out -- until time expires.

@NuclearHoagie Given the existence of ride out a storm or any situation and run out the clock (a firmly attested usage) in sports, I disagree.

I think ride definitely has a you are not in control of when or how this turns out meaning, whereas run is normally used to convey actively wasting as much time as possible to prevent losing.

I am the OP, and I thank Lambie very much for answering my  question. Now I understand it better, and I wonder how the phrase is not in any dictionary, not even in the Urban dictionary if most native speakers understand the meaning. Also, I appreciate all others comments.  Thank you,

The notion of e.g. "riding out a storm" suggests deliberate acceptance of the consequences of inaction as being preferable to the possible consequences of attempted action, and a lack of control over how long such inaction may be needed.  Substituting the metanym "clock" doesn't change the fundamental notion.  By contrast, "running out the clock" often implies an effort to make the clock run out as quickly as possible, by working to prevent things that would delay its expiration.

@supercat The main point is that ride out a storm is one thing and "run out the clock" is **another. And it's metonym by the way. "run out the clock" in sports means you are already winning. It does not mean an effort to make the clock run out more quickly. That doesn't mean anything anyway. It means hold onto the ball until the time is up.

@Lambie: In some sports, "run out the clock" does involve trying to expedite the expiry of the clock.  In American football, if a team would need to score a first down to keep possession until the time expired, but would want the opposing team to have minimal time available if it fails to score a first down, it would avoid passing plays in favor of running plays, since an incomplete pass will stop the clock until play starts for the next down, but a tackle after a running play would leave the clock running during the 20 seconds or so prior to the next snap.

@supercat Clocks are clocks, you can't expedite their running. What you describe is tactics. And by the way, if should not be followed by would. If  any time period has not yet expired, the point is to keep possession of the ball so the other team has no chance to do anything with it. There's no point here getting into the nitty-gritty of American football.

@Lambie: In American football, certain actions will momentarily stop the game clock until the start of the next play, but other actions won't.  A team that is trying to "run out the clock" will act deliberately to avoid actions that would stop the game clock.  If a play starts with 1:55 on the game clock, the game might be over in less than two minutes if the team with possession is able to run out the clock, but of that time about a minute would likely need to be active play.  At least in American football, "running out the clock" is not a passive activity.

@supercat Ok, maybe American football is not the best example. But it works in other sports (soccer, rugby, baseball, basketball)  where possessing the ball just stops the other team from scoring. Let's just drop this now. It's way beyond the scope of the question.

@Lambie: I think it's important to recognize the distinction between "ride out" and "run out"; the latter often requires deliberate action to prevent something from happening before the clock expires, while the former implies passive waiting.
